# Compare columns from 2 different tables and get the difference in amount

Tags: sql

I have a scenario where I have 2 tables with the same foreign key and amount column, such as below:

```
TABLE 1:
ForeignKey       Amount
----------      -------------
12              20.0
12              30.0
13              20.0
21              10.0
21              10.0

TABLE 2:
ForeignKey       Amount
----------      -------------
12              60.0
12              25.0
13              30.0
21              10.0
21              10.0


EXPECTED OUTPUT:
ForeignKey       Amount
----------      -------------
12              35.0
13              10.0
21              0
```

I am using MSSQL

I want to compare the amounts aggregate amount per ForeignKey of each table and get the difference. I realize that I could put these into DataTable objects (C#) and do some complicated looping, but I am wondering if there's a more elegant SQL approach I can take. I am not very strong with SQL. Could someone point me in a general direction that I could explore in order to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Please show expected output.

Comment: what RDBMS are you using ? SQL Server, Oracle , MySQL etc and what do you mean by compare results ? what would be the result set of the two tables shown in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.ForeignKey, t1.total AS total1, t2.total AS total2, t1.total-t2.total AS difference
FROM 
(
    SELECT ForeignKey,sum(Amount) AS total 
    FROM table1 
    GROUP BY ForeignKey
) t1 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ForeignKey,sum(Amount) AS total 
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY ForeignKey
) t2 
ON t1.ForeignKey=t2.ForeignKey
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;with t as (select ForeignKey,amount from [table 1]
union
select ForeignKey,-amount from [table 2])
select ForeignKey,sum(amount) from t
group by ForeignKey
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T1.SUM1-T2.SUM1 AS DIFFERENCE FROM
(SELECT [FOREIGNKEY],SUM(AMOUNT) AS SUM1
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY [FOREIGNKEY]) AS T1 INNER JOIN (SELECT [FOREIGNKEY],SUM(AMOUNT) AS SUM1
FROM TABLE2
GROUP BY [FOREIGNKEY]) AS T2 ON T1.FOREIGNKEY = T2.FOREIGNKEY
```